# Can we use new keyword with scala traits

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits

I am reading all over that we cannot instantiate the trait but when I am running this code, it's working fine. I am confused about scala traits could someone explain.

```
trait X {
  def a: Int
  def b: String
}

object test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    new X() {
      override def a: Int = 1

      override def b: String = "as"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you actually did is providing `X` a class body `{ }` and created an anonymous class inline that extends the trait.
In addition - all members of that trait have a concrete implementation - that's why it works.